# Is it possible to count number of records on biztalk send port

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a scenario, where I receive an XML file which has 3 nodes (header, body, and footer), and the 2nd node (body) may have records in itself. I do map those records in body to a flat file and output it to a specific folder. But it may happen in some cases that the body node contains 0 records.

I need to make the send port output file only if there are records, and do not output file with 0 kb size.

Any suggestions how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two possible approaches:

1. The elegant approach - create a Custom Receive Pipeline Component which uses XPath to determine whether the body node contains records. If it does, pass the message through; if not, return an empty stream so no message is published to the Message Box.
2. The less elegant approach - receive the message (header, body and footer) in an Orchestration and using the same XPath statement as in (1), determine whether the body node contains records. If it does, use a Send Shape to send the message; if it doesn't, let the orchestration terminate without sending a message.

In either scenario, I would perform your map on the Send Port (which will also be configured with the Flat-File Assembler). If you opt for the messaging-only solution (1 above), you will need to filter on either the Receive Port Name or Message Type (or some other promoted property).

I have marked the first option as 'elegant' as processing can be completed as the message is parsed by the Receive Pipeline and no additional processing is required (i.e. spinning up an orchestration) to achieve the desired result.